# How to call AppCompatActivity onCreate in unit test using Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I want to write a simple unit test for the Android Activity class. The test runs fine while Activity is extended, however, when extending AppCompatActivity the test fails with:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
>       at activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:15)

MainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        finish()
    }
}
```

Test code using Mockito:

```
private lateinit var mainActivitySpy: MainActivity

@Before
fun setUp() {
    mainActivitySpy = spy(MainActivity())
}

@Test
fun `Test case`() {
    mainActivitySpy.onCreate(mock())

    verify(mainActivitySpy).finish()
}
```

I have tried adding the following code but to no avail.

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make this code work using the only JUnit+Mockito and no other testing frameworks, like Roboelectric, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using PowerMock.

```
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
```

Then in my test class I have...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ReportFragment.class })
public class AddEditBeaconActivityTests {

    @Test
    public void test_onCreate() {
        // Mock some data
        mockStatic(ReportFragment.class);
        MyActivity activity = spy(new MyActivity());
        doNothing().when(activity).initScreen();
        doNothing().when(activity).setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        doReturn(mock(AppCompatDelegate.class)).when(activity).getDelegate();

        // Call the method
        activity.onCreate(null);

        // Verify that it worked
        verify(activity, times(1)).setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        verify(activity, times(1)).initScreen();
    }
}
```

Then here is what MyActivity.java looks like...

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        initScreen();
    }
}
```

This works because your are mocking some of the internal methods/classes that are called when you call super.onCreate().  More specifically...

1. The NullPointerException that you are seeing is because your mocked class doesn't have a AppCompatDelegate and so it tries to create one.  If you passed in a mocked AppCompatDelegate with `doReturn(mock(AppCompatDelegate.class)).when(activity).getDelegate();` you can get around this problem.
2. Eventually, the SupportActivity will try to call `ReportFragment.injectIfNeededIn(this);`.  Simply mocking this static class with mockStatic(ReportFragment.class) will mock this call out.  Don't forget to add the two lines to the top of your class: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest({ ReportFragment.class })`

I am not going to argue whether you should be mocking the onCreate method or not.  David makes a very valid argument.  If you truly need to test the onCreate method in unit tests, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make this code work using the only JUnit+Mockito and no other testing frameworks, like Roboelectric, etc?

No, there is no easy way to do this without resorting to a framework. And the real question is why you would even want to try. Tests against an Activity in which every single dependency is mocked start to degenerate into "testing tautologies" where the test is simply mirrors the logic of the Activity without adding any value.

The conventional wisdom in Android is to keep Activities, Fragments etc. as lightweight as possible since they are difficult to unit test. The business logic you need can be handled by a testable Presenter or ViewModel. Your book or tutorial should cover this.

If you must write a test against an Activity you can write an Instrumented Unit Test in which a real Activity is instantiated on a device. See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests) for how to do this.